# While deploying through workbench, getting exception : SOQL TYPEOF expressions are not supported in this organization

Tags: soql, lightning-aura-components, controller, deployment

I am trying to deploy some components through retreive-deploy fascility of Workbench and while deploying, the deployment of lightning controller class is failing with error:

SOQL TYPEOF expressions are not supported in this organization

I have used following query in the class which usees TYPEOF clause:

```
SELECT 
  TYPEOF SetupOwner
      WHEN Profile THEN Name
      WHEN User THEN Name               
  END,
  FROM MyCustomSetting__c
```

Do we need to unable something in target org to allow use of TYPEOF?

Answer (score 2):

See this article [SOQL TYPEOF expressions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175996&language=en_US&type=1) that contains this important information:

> Currently, this feature is only available in sandbox environment, This
>   feature is not available in production organization. Please contact
>   Support to get this feature enabled in your sandbox organization if
>   you would like to test it.  Once this feature is generally available
>   (GA), support will be able to enable this in production (paid)
>   organizations too.

This means that you cannot use this feature in production right now and there is no definite date when you will be able to use it in production. So it's an "experiment only" feature.

Comment: But in my DE org , I can use it. And my target org is a DE org as well.

Comment: It doesn't mean you can't use it in production...it means you need support to enable it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson So " Once this feature is generally available (GA)" doesn't apply?

Comment: Ah. Hmm...I guess I misread that. They might...

Answer (score 1):

`TYPEOF` will be Generally Available in the [Summer 19 Release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_api_soql.htm#rn_api_soql)